# Make a part of interface not to be optional

Tags: typescript

I want to change a property `x` of the interface `Foo` not to be `Optional`:

```js
// thirdparty.ts
interface Foo {
  x?: ComplexObjectType,
  y?: string,
  z?: string
}

// main.ts
import { Foo } from "thirdparty";
type Bar = // same as `Foo` except that the field `x` is public
```

How to do that?

Comment: Have you done any research? Any reading on TypeScript? Have you read up on what makes a property [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties)?

Comment: Yes, `?` makes a field to Optional. I want to know how to apply `NonNullable` partially.

Comment: Not clear what you want

Comment: `type Bar = Foo & { x: Foo['x'] } `

Comment: @ritaj - I was trying that with a `typeof`, foolish me. You should post that as an answer (or linka  duplicate, if you iknow of one).

Comment: *"same as `Foo` except that the field `x` is public"* Huh? don't you mean "required" (rather than "public")? They're all public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make one property required, which you know in advance, you can easily do it like this:

```
type Bar = Foo & { x: Foo['x'] }

const bar: Bar = {}; // Property 'x' is missing in type '{}' but required in type...
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHANhADwHkAjAKwgTABUBPbFAbwFgAoZD5OALmQGcwUUAHMA3GwC+bNqEixEKAGLp0yFu2QEA-Lww58xcpRr0IAGjYdaO-oJEWNALxsChIYZOmswp5ACE4KGQAXmRlVQAyNU1ecIBtACICBIBdZAlxVjYEdBABGP9AkLVLTlpeBNoEyVEgA)

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Foo {
  x?: ComplexObjectType,
  y?: string,
  z?: string
}

type Require<T, K extends keyof T> = T & {
    [P in K]-?: T[P]
  };

type Bar = Require<Foo, 'x'>;
```

Comment: That does [seem to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=34&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHANhADwHkAjAKwgTABUBPbFAbwFgAoZD5OALmQGcwUUAHMA3GwC+bNqEixEKAGLp0yFu2QEA-Lww58xcpRr0IAGjYdaO-oJEWNALxsChIYZOmswp5ACUIAEcAV2AoCAAeajNkAGlkQkgQABM+ZABrCFp0GGRqAD5kAF485AAyNUtOAG0ABWRQOIBdAFobajqmqolxVjYfBmQAITgoYv8g0PCI5XQYgHICefzetgR0EAFNXhGxkvVOZFpeACJaE8lRIA), though I like ritaj's `type Bar = Foo & (x: Foo["x"]);` better. :-)